# Accessing Dictionary within object within dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary

I am using the Yellow Pages API to access business listings based on the phone's location. Results are returned in JSON and I am parsing this successfully:

```
    do {
         let searchResultsData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

    print(searchResultsData)
.
.
.
```

The result is a Dictionary that contains a confusing hierarchy of other dictionaries and objects.

Here is a console printout of the main dictionary content:

```
{
    searchResult =     {
        metaProperties =         {
            didYouMean = "";
            errorCode = "";
            inputParams =             {
                "@xsi.type" = searchRequest;
                appId = xxxxxxxx; 
                dnt = "";
                format = json;
                listingCount = 2;
                phoneSearch = 0;
                radius = 5;
                requestId = "a75efeb9-de0a-4411-8ee9-c6c43f3867e8";
                searchLocation = "37.33233141:-122.0312186";
                shortUrl = 0;
                sort = distance;
                term = pizza;
                termType = "";
                test = "";
                userAgent = "Determine%20use%20location/1 CFNetwork/758.1.6 Darwin/14.5.0";
                userIpAddress = "22.1.2.33";
                userReferrer = internalReferrer;
                visitorId = xxxxxxxxxx;
            };
            listingCount = 2;
            message = "";
            relatedCategories =             {
                "@xsi.type" = rServiceFacets;
                relatedCategory =                 (
                                        {
                        count = 121;
                        name = Pizza;
                    },
                                        {
                        count = 105;
                        name = Restaurants;
                    },
                                        {
                        count = 78;
                        name = "Take Out Restaurants";
                    },
                                        {
                        count = 41;
                        name = "Italian Restaurants";
                    },
                                        {
                        count = 30;
                        name = Caterers;
                    }
                );
            };
            requestId = "a75efeb9-de0a-4411-8ee9-c6c43f3867e8";
            resultCode = Success;
            searchCity = Cupertino;
            searchLat = "37.323056";
            searchLon = "-122.031111";
            searchState = CA;
            searchType = Category;
            searchZip = 95015;
            totalAvailable = 121;
            trackingRequestURL = "http://c.ypcdn.com/2/i/rtd?vrid=gpnx7mtbzw&rid=a75efeb9-de0a-4411-8ee9-c6c43f3867e8&ptid=gpnx7mtbzw&lsrc=MDM&cp=__";
            ypcAttribution = "";
        };
        searchListings =         {
            searchListing =             (
                                {
                    adImage = "";
                    adImageClick = "";
                    additionalText = " ";
                    audioURL = "";
                    averageRating = "2.86";
                    baseClickURL = "http://c.ypcdn.com/2/c/rtd?vrid=gpnx7mtbzw&rid=a75efeb9-de0a-4411-8ee9-c6c43f3867e8&ptid=gpnx7mtbzw&ypid=17510978&lid=17510978&lsrc=MDM";
                    businessName = "BJ's Restaurants";
                    businessNameURL = "http://c.ypcdn.com/2/c/rtd?vrid=gpnx7mtbzw&rid=a75efeb9-de0a-4411-8ee9-c6c43f3867e8&ptid=gpnx7mtbzw&ypid=17510978&lid=17510978&tl=1600&lsrc=MDM&dest=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yellowpages.com%2Fcupertino-ca%2Fmip%2Fbjs-restaurants-17510978%3Ffrom%3Dpubapi_gpnx7mtbzw";
                    categories = " Restaurants|Take Out Restaurants|Brew Pubs|American Restaurants|Pizza|Family Style Restaurants|Beer & Ale|";
                    city = Cupertino;
                    claimed = 0;
                    claimedStatus = 0;
                   // removed for space
                },
                                {
                   // removed for space
                   // second listing follows same structure
                }
            );
        };
    };
}
```

I removed most of the first listing and all of the second listing for space purposes. The listing structure is consistent. The number of listings returned can be controlled through an API parameter.

As you can see the first item in the main dictionary is another dictionary named searchResult. I can successfully access this through:

```
let dataReturned = searchResultsData["searchResult"]!
```

However, this is where I get stuck. The Variables View shows that dataReturned is of type NSDictionary but then shows it contains and NSMutableDictionary which contains an NSDictionary which contains and NSObject which contains or is named 'isa' of type NSDictionary with 2 key value pairs, one of which is the key I am interested in, named searchListings.

I have done numerous searches and tried ways of drilling down further but keep getting errors which all basically boils down to being unable to get past the objects between dataReturned and the key:values I am interested in.

The question makes a lot more sense if you see the screen capture here: 
http://screencast.com/t/VozRgLEzriD

I am using Xcode 7.1. Any advice on how to drill down into this dictionary structure would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You've got problems because the Dictionary you get doesn't tell you anything about what it contains. You would have to do something like this:

```
if let
    searchRes = searchResultsData["searchResult"] as? [NSObject : AnyObject],
    listings = searchRes["searchListings"] as? [NSObject : AnyObject],
    .... {
        // here is your code
}
```

but that's really cumbersome. There is a great alternative: [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#why-is-the-typical-json-handling-in-swift-not-good). It enables a pattern like this (example taken from SwiftyJSON):

```
let json = JSON(data: data)
if let userName = json[0]["user"]["name"].string {
    //Now you got your value
}
```

The json data object still doesn't tell you what it contains, but at least you don't need to check every time.

Comment: I have come across mention of SwiftyJSON in my attempts to resolve this. I will look into this some more, thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

I created this online utility (http://www.json4swift.com) that transforms your json into swift representable models that you can drill down into the structure easily. All you need to do is paste your Json and copy the generated models to your project, and then use it like this:

```
    //Create instance for base model representation
    let responseModel = Json4Swift_Base(dictionary: searchResultsData)
```

And then your response model becomes an object based representation of your dictionary

Comment: How to access data from model class